# RMarkdown: Show plot from list of pre-existing plots based on user input

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

First I create R-Markdown file and make a list of two simple plots:

---

````
title: "test"
author: "Zhaochen He"
date: "2023-03-14"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r make_plots, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
plot1 = ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cyl, y = cty)) + geom_point()
plot2 = ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cyl, y = hwy)) + geom_point()      
myplots = list(plot1, plot2)
```
````

Now I try to display plot #1 and it works perfectly. Displaying plot #2 also works perfectly.

```
renderPlot({
  myplots[[1]]
})
```

Results: [image]

But, if I try to have the user select which plot to show, it doesn't work at all. A selection pull down is created, but no plot is displayed.

```
inputPanel(
  selectInput('num', label = 'number', choices = 1:2, selected = 1)
)
renderPlot({
  myplots[[input$num]]
})
```

Results: [image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `selectInput()` converts 1 to "1". This worked for me:

```
renderPlot({
  myplots[[as.numeric(input$num)]]
})
```